# SQL Function to Increment 6 character ISO date field with format 'YYYYWW'

Tags: sql-server, isodate

I have several tables that store weekly data using an 6 character year and ISO week, with format 'YYYYWW'. For example the first week in 2020 would be ‘202001’. I'm using SQL Server 2012(SP1) 11.0.3156.

I am trying to write an SQL function that allows me to increment the week I am on, so that I can write queries that look forward and backwards in time. So my function would work something like this:

```sql
PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202244', -2)  would simply return/print ‘202242’
```

I want the function to take an integer as the 2nd parameter and move that number of weeks, +ive forward in time, -ive backwards in time.

Simple enough, but not all years have 52 weeks. So I wrote the function to cope with that aspect. But other ISO week issues are stopping my function from working correctly (or at least how I would expect it to work). I’m running this in Europe, don’t know if that would impact how the ISO works in SQL, or if that is the issue.

I can’t figure out how to fix this. Has any one got any ideas on how to resolve this? Any help appreciated, thanks. Here is the SQL code and some example outputs:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.increment_week(@week_to_increment char(6), @increment_weeks int)
RETURNS char(6) 
AS 
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @year_start_date date, @current_week_date date, @new_date date
    DECLARE @Week_Of_Year_Text char(2), @year_Text char(4)
    DECLARE @week_of_first_of_Year int, @current_week_int int
    
    SET @year_start_date        = CAST(LEFT(@week_to_increment, 4) + '0101' AS DATE)
    SET @current_week_int       = CAST(RIGHT(@week_to_increment, 2) AS INT)
    SET @week_of_first_of_Year  = DATEPART(isoww, @year_start_date)
    /* If start week is 53 move on one week */
    SET @year_start_date        = DATEADD(week, IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 53, 1, 0), @year_start_date) 
    SET @current_week_date      = DATEADD(week, @current_week_int, @year_start_date) 
    SET @new_date               = DATEADD(week, @increment_weeks, @current_week_date)  
    SET @week_Of_Year_Text      = RIGHT('00'+ CAST(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @new_date) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)
    SET @year_Text              = CONVERT(CHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, @new_date), @new_date)))
    RETURN @year_Text + @week_Of_Year_Text
END
GO

Here are some sample calls to the function:

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202244', -2) /* correct returns '202242' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202244', 0) /* correct returns '202244' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202244', 2) /* correct returns '202246' */
 
PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202201', -2) /* correct returns '202251' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202201', 0) /* correct returns '202201' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202201', 2) /* correct returns '202201' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202044', -2) /* wrong returns '202043' not '202042' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202044', 0) /* wrong returns '202045' not '202044' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202044', 2) /* wrong returns '202047' not '202046' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202001', -2) /* wrong returns '201952' not '201951' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202001', 0) /* wrong returns '202002' not '202001' */

PRINT dbo.increment_week ('202001', 2) /* wrong returns '202044' not '202003' */
```

With some inspiration from the comments I added a case statement which now seems to work. Could be streamlined a bit, but here it is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.increment_week(@week_to_increment char(6), @increment_weeks int)
RETURNS char(6) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @year_start_date date, @current_week_date date, @new_date date
    DECLARE @Week_Of_Year_Text char(2), @year_Text char(4)
    DECLARE @week_of_first_of_Year int, @current_week_int int
    
    SET @year_start_date        = CAST(LEFT(@week_to_increment, 4) + '0101' AS DATE)
    SET @week_of_first_of_Year  = DATEPART(isoww, @year_start_date)
    
    /*===========works but code could be simplified?=======*/
    SET @year_start_date = CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 1 
            THEN @year_start_date /* Sunday    */
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 2 
            THEN DATEADD(day,  IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 1, -1, 6), @year_start_date) /* Monday    */
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 3 
            THEN DATEADD(day,  IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 1, -2, 5), @year_start_date) /* Tuesday   */
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 4 
            THEN DATEADD(day,  IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 1, -3, 4), @year_start_date) /* Wednesday */
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 5 
            THEN DATEADD(day,  IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 1, -4, 3), @year_start_date) /* Thursday  */
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 6 
            THEN DATEADD(day,  IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 1, -5, 2), @year_start_date) /* Friday    */
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, @year_start_date) = 7 
            THEN DATEADD(day,  IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 1, -6, 1), @year_start_date) /* Saturday  */
        ELSE @year_start_date
    END

    SET @year_start_date        = DATEADD(week, IIF(@week_of_first_of_Year = 53, 1, 0), @year_start_date) /* If start week is 53 move on one week */
    SET @current_week_int       = CAST(RIGHT(@week_to_increment, 2) AS INT)
    SET @current_week_date      = DATEADD(week, @current_week_int, @year_start_date) 
    SET @new_date               = DATEADD(week, @increment_weeks, @current_week_date)  
    SET @week_Of_Year_Text      = RIGHT('00'+ CAST(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, @new_date) AS NVARCHAR(2)), 2)
    SET @year_Text              = CONVERT(CHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, @new_date), @new_date)))
    RETURN @year_Text + @week_Of_Year_Text
END
GO
```

Comment: Your statement *"with format 'YYYYWW'"* conflicts with the latter *"For example the first week in 2020 would be ‘20201"*. The format `yyyyww` would produce the value `202001`; yuio are using `yyyyww`.

Comment: Why not add, or subtract, a week to the date, and then get the ISO Week value? Feels like you're overly complicating the problem. Otherwise, have you considered using a calendar table?

Comment: Larnu, Thanks, I fixed the typo. My early attempts were quite simple but did not work in all cases. It looks complicated but what I do in there is what you suggested, it converts the ISO week to a date, then increments the date, then converts it back to the required format. But it does not always give the expected result. I agree that a simple bit of code should suffice, but I have not managed to find a simple bit of code that works correctly all the time. Perhaps someone on here could suggest something? Peter

Comment: "I can’t figure out how to fix this." You fix this by not messing around with date arithmetic. It's hard and complicated and full of pitfalls and gotchas that will drive you insane. 
Instead, store a date and use the already built in capabilities of the database - `DatePart` seems like the obvious choice to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as follow in order to build your week movement:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.increment_week(@week_to_increment int, @increment_weeks int)
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @RetVal int;

  DECLARE @year INT = @week_to_increment/100
  DECLARE @CW INT = @week_to_increment%100

  SET @CW = @CW -1;    

  DECLARE @d DATE = CONVERT(DATE, CAST(@year * 10000 + 101 AS NVARCHAR(8)), 112)
  SET @d =  DATEADD(DAY, @CW*7, DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, '1900-01-6', @d)%7, @d))
    
  DECLARE @MovedWeek DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @increment_weeks * 7, @d)

  SET @RetVal = DATEPART(YEAR, @MovedWeek) * 100 + DATEPART(iso_week, @MovedWeek);
  RETURN @RetVal;
END
GO
```

A short description of the idea:

- you get January 1st of your year
- you move to the first sunday (or monday - depending if you count sunday as first or as last day of the week)
- you then add your initial week-1 to this date (-1 since you already are in week 1 after step 2)
- afterwards you jump up or down the number of weeks defined in MoveWeeks

Comment: Having read the above, I added a case statement to my function which seems to work. This could probably be simplified, to read better. I could not add it here as it is too long, it is in the bottom of the question...

Comment: I guess the CASE is not needed here! That's the idea behind `DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, '1900-01-6', @d)%7, @d)` - 1900-01-06 should be a sunday. Therefore I calculate the diff between this date and my initial date, get the remaining days by calculating %7 and add this to my date - so I am on a sunday again. Just execute my example from the answer - I tried with several of your dates and it worked out fine

Comment: @PeterM I changed my answer - it contains a function now. If you require CHAR instead of INT, you can modify the function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try with bellow function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[increment_week] (@yyyyww CHAR(6), @increment_weeks INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @StartDatetime DATE;
    DECLARE @yyyy CHAR(4) = LEFT(@yyyyww,4);
    DECLARE @ww TINYINT= RIGHT(@yyyyww,2);

    SET @StartDatetime = CAST(@yyyy AS DATETIME) - DAY(CAST(@yyyy  AS DATETIME)) + 1 + (@ww - 1) * 7;

    SET @StartDatetime =  DATEADD(WW, @increment_weeks, @StartDatetime);

    RETURN CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, CONVERT(varchar(10), @StartDatetime,120)), RIGHT(CONCAT('00', DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StartDatetime,120))), 2))

END
GO

PRINT dbo.increment_week('202001',2)

--DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[increment_week]
```

Comment: @PeterM , If it's solved your problem then mark it as solution.